# `php artisan serve` starting wrong

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-artisan

When I am starting my local Laravel project with `php artisan serve` it is always beginning with "Controller" word and in the corner of every page in my project starts with this same word. I couldn't find where is my mistake.

My command:

[image: My Cmd command]

Comment: Have you searched your project for the word "Controller"? You might have one before an opening PHP tag, like `Controller<?php ...`

Comment: use serve command with -v option, this shows a stack trace which helps to find where is the problem: `php artisan -v serve`

Answer (score 0):

you have a **Controller** word in your **Source Code** which shouldnt be.

maybe its in html or blade (not php) or maybe you were **echo Controller** somewhere to trace something and you have forgotten to remove that.

you can use **Find in Project** feature of an IDE to find The Word and remove it out.

Answer (score 0):

I recently went through the same situation, in my case php artisan serve always started with the number 1:

[image]

Mission impossible to search for 1 using CTRL + F in the folder. So I quickly looked through all my config files and found the **number 1 before an opening php tag**:

[image]